# InvalidValueError: not an Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to get the google maps polygon function to work. The map is showing but I am having this error: InvalidValueError: not an Array. Any suggestions? Please help thank you!

Here are my codes:

*Homepage.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.page.scss'],
})

export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  map: any;
  @ViewChild('map', { read: ElementRef, static: false }) mapRef: ElementRef;

  polygon: any = [];
  triangleCoords: any = [
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190 },
    { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
    { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 },
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190 }
  ];

  constructor() {
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.showMap();
  }

  addPolygon(triangleCoords) {
    for (let triangleCoord of triangleCoords) {
      let bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: triangleCoord,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
      });
      bermudaTriangle.setMap(this.map);
    }
  }

  showMap() {
    const location = new google.maps.LatLng(24.886, -70.268);
    const options = {
      center: location,
      zoom: 5,
      disabledDefaultUI: true
    }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement, options);
    this.addPolygon(this.triangleCoords);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

*homepage.html*

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button menu="main-menu"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true" class="ion-padding">
  <div #map id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

The error says its an array but im not sure what to add and remove.

Comment: What variable `not an Array`?

Answer (score 0):

`triangleCoords` is a property of your class, to access it your need to add `this`:

```
let bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: this.triangleCoord, // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Fix 
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
});
```

As it is in your code, `triangleCoord` was undefined in the context of the `addPolygon` method, which explains the error message.